# Regex for containing a word with specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to find whether a sentence contain a word. if the word having prefix or postfix then the word is in valid but valid for some specific characters   like ,.*+- etc below are some example. I am searching for **process** word, for valid sentence I make them bold

1. processes
2. **process**
3. Processing
4. **process-specific**
5. processed
6. processor
7. procession
8. **Inter-process**
9. uniprocessor
10. multiprocessing
11. **process's**
12. **"process"**
13. **process10**

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: [-'"]process[-'"] use this regex but it only height light "process"

Comment: processes is also invalid

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the word-boundary class (`\b`):

```
\bprocess\b
```

In a case-insensitive regex match that should give you the correct result:

```
string[] strings = new string[] {
    @"processes",
    @"process",
    @"Processing",
    @"process-specific",
    @"processed",
    @"processor",
    @"procession",
    @"Inter-process",
    @"uniprocessor",
    @"multiprocessing",
    @"process's",
    @"""process""",
    @"process10"
};

foreach (string s in strings)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\bprocess\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    else
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

[image]

If trailing numbers are allowed, do:

```
\bprocess(?:\b|\d+)
```

[image]

Comment: needs to be case insensitive

Comment: So you made a modification to the string to scan it...?

Comment: @Jay absolutely true. Updated answer with `Regex.IgnoreCase`

Comment: There, I reversed my vote.. Good job.

Comment: ```(\bprocess\b|process[^a-z].*)```

should also catch the "process10" or similar

Comment: @johnb `\bprocess(?:\b|\d+)` should do

Comment: @ jonb, that adds exponential time to the match based on the length... your additional `.` and `*` quantifiers are pointless here as the boundary is already defined... furthermore this is why you don't use a Regex...

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen absolutely correct